# Kendo UI Tab- Reload tab every time it is clicked

Tags: kendo-ui

I have a kendo UI tab, and each tab is binding to an Ajax function. I want my  tab to fire ajax call to get fresh content every time the tab is changed, not just the first time. Is there a configuration or recommended way that I can achieve this?

Comment: Funny, I'm getting the exact opposite behaviour (it reloads all the time) and I want to prevent it!!!

Comment: I think by default, the tabs will be cached and do not reload itself every time you click it.

Comment: Not in my case! They are reloaded all the time!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hello this could be easily through the **reload** method of the TabStrip.

```
var ts = $(tabstrip).data().kendoTabStrip
ts.tabGroup.on('click','li',function(e){        
    ts.reload($(this));
})
```

Comment: I use this solution, but the tab strip load more than one time in each click.  Where I can locate the code so that only reload once per click?