# Kendo Tabstrip click event fired only once

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I am using kendo tabstrip having two tabs.

Tab I:
Add User.
Tab II:
It has a dropdown that will be refreshed every time when a user is added from *Tab1*

I need to call a javascript method to refresh the drop down of Tab II each time it is called.
I have used tabstrip "Activate","Select","Show" events but it is only firing once while the tab is clicked.

```
     @(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
    .Name("CWUserTabStrip")
.Events(events => events            
            .Activate("onActivate")
.Select("onSelect")
.ContentLoad("onContentLoad")

        )
    .Items(tabstrip =>
    {
        tabstrip.Add().Text("User Creation")
            .Selected(true)
            .LoadContentFrom("_CWUserCreationTab", "User");

        tabstrip.Add().Text("User Allocation")
            .LoadContentFrom("_CWUserAllocationTab", "User");

    })
)
```

Any trick to fire the tabstrip click event each time a tab is clicked ??

Comment: probable duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16067258/kendo-ui-tab-reload-tab-every-time-it-is-clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can attach your own event with jquery:

```
$(function () {
    $("div#CWUserTabStrip ul li:nth-child(2)").on("click", function () {
        alert('clicked');
    });
});
```

You can put this in the view where the tab strip is, just make sure you set the child element corresponding to the tab number in your tab strip. I tested it and it works nicely. Check it out.